# Input string was not in correct format at textchange

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I've written this code

```
private void txtRate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
  try   
  {   
    decimal qty;   
    decimal price;   
    decimal amt = 0;   
    qty = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text);  
    price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text);  
    amt = qty * price;  
    txtAmount.Text = amt.ToString();    
  }   
  catch (Exception ex)   
  {   
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);   
  }   
}
```

For getting an value in `txtAmount` textbox automatically and I can get it correctly.

After that I want to clear all textbox, so I wrote this

```
txtProdSerName.Text = "";  
txtQuantity.Text = "";   
txtRate.Text = "";   
txtAmount.Text = "";
```

but I am getting error

> input string was not in a correct format

because `textchange` event occurs again here.

PLEASE GIVE ME SOME SUGGESTION OR SOLUTION ABOUT THIS

Comment: On which line you get this error exactly? And what are the values of `txtQuantity.Text` and `txtRate.Text` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your `txtQuantity.Text` and `txtRate.Text` is not empty because TextChangeEvent fire when you empty your textbox values.

```
private void txtRate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
  try   
  {   
      decimal qty;   
      decimal price;   
      decimal amt = 0;
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQuantity.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRate.Text))
      {
          qty = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text);  
          price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text);  
          amt = qty * price;  
          txtAmount.Text = amt.ToString();    
      }     
  }   
  catch (Exception ex)   
  {   
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);   
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the code a little to look like this:

```
private void txtRate_TextChanged()
{
   try   
  {
    if(txtRate.Text.Trim() == string.Empty) return;
    decimal qty;   
    decimal price;   
    decimal amt = 0;   
    qty = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text);  
    price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text);  
    amt = qty * price;  
    txtAmount.Text = amt.ToString();    
  }   
  catch (Exception ex)   
  {   
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);   
  }
}
```

This way, you return out of `txtRate_TextChanged()` event each time txtRate is empty.

Comment: just returning from event handler if string is empty , very clear :)

Comment: :-) @SudhakarTillapudi :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Problem :** `TextChanged` Event will be fired everytime the `Textbox` value changes. it will be fired even if you clear the `TextBox` value and leads to the exception.

**Solution 1:** you can `unsubscribe` from the `TextChanged` Event before clearing the Text Feilds and `subscribe` to it again after clearing the TextFeilds.so that while clearing the TextBox values it can not call the `TextChanged` Event as there is no `subscribed` event handler for `TextChanged`.

Try This:

```
txtRate.TextChanged -= new System.EventHandler(txtRate_TextChanged);  

txtProdSerName.Text = "";  
txtQuantity.Text = "";   
txtRate.Text = "";   
txtAmount.Text = ""; 

txtRate.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(txtRate_TextChanged);
```

**Solution 2:**  you can create a `boolean` variable and check if it is really a `TextChanged` Event.

**Step 1 :** Create `Boolean` variable and initialise it to `true`.
**Step 2 :** change the `Boolean` variable value to `false` before clearing the `Textbox` values.
**Step 3 :** change the `Boolean` variable back to `true` after clearing the `Textbox` values.
**Step 4 :** execute your `TextChanged` event handler code only if the `Boolean` variable is `true`.

Try This:

```
private bool isTextChangedEvent = true;
private void txtRate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
  if(isTextChangedEvent)
  {
    try   
    {   
      decimal qty;   
      decimal price;   
      decimal amt = 0;   
      qty = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text);  
      price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text);  
      amt = qty * price;  
      txtAmount.Text = amt.ToString();    
    }   
    catch (Exception ex)   
    {   
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);   
    }   
  }
}
```

while clearing `TextBox` values:

```
isTextChangedEvent = false;
txtProdSerName.Text = "";  
txtQuantity.Text = "";   
txtRate.Text = "";   
txtAmount.Text = ""; 
isTextChangedEvent = true;
```

Comment: attaching and detaching events is expensive. any other elegant solution you have?

Comment: @Aniket: i agree with you, let me edit my answer with `solution2`.

Comment: @Aniket: edited my answer with `Solution2` , i think this should help the OP.

Comment: You are adding an extra state, that's usually a bad thing to do..keep the programs state-free and you will definitely produce some good, failproof code.

Comment: @Aniket: sorry i didnt get it `adding an extra state`, is it in 2nd solution?

Comment: Yeah, the `isTextChangedEvent` in the 2nd solution represents a state.

Comment: @Aniket: Okay, Thanks you for guiding me towards right direction :)

Comment: Not a problem at all man, here is more for the 'right' direction :-P http://bigshopper.in/products/Real-World-Functional-Programming-With-Examples-In-F-And-C

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**:

When you change the text it fires the event, and before that you are setting 
`txtQuantity` `txtrate` to `""`, and in that event you are using `txtQuantity` `txtrate` values(which are actually `Empty` now, so they can not be parsed to `decimal`) that's why when it tries to change the text of `txtRate` it finds `txtQuantity` value is `""` (Empty) and throws the exception.

**Solution**:

Put your this code in a separate method:

```
private void changeTxtRateValue()
{
    try   
      {   
        decimal qty;   
        decimal price;   
        decimal amt = 0;   
        qty = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text);  
        price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text);  
        amt = qty * price;  
        txtAmount.Text = amt.ToString();    
      }   
      catch (Exception ex)   
      {   
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);   
      }
}
```

and call the method only when `txtQuantity` is not `Empty`:

```
private void txtRate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
    if(txtQuantity.Text != String.Empty)
        changeTxtRateValue();
}
```

**Best Practise Advice:**

Don't use `""` to set an string `empty`, because it is not `empty`.

Always use `String.Empty`.

Use this code:

```
txtProdSerName.Text = String.Empty;  
txtQuantity.Text = String.Empty;   
txtRate.Text = String.Empty;   
txtAmount.Text = String.Empty;
```

It'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the right control in your application. Please use NumericUpDown control instead.